# Regex to match the line that ends with the exact word rather than similar words

Tags: python, regex, search, pattern-matching

I am trying to parse a config file and display the output on a web UI. However, some of the regex I have written returns extra results. For instance,

```
lbvs = lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek
lb_vserver_binding = '^bind\s+lb\s+vserver\s+%s\s+([^\s+]+)' %(lbvs)
for line in lb_file_memory:
        if re.match(lb_vserver_binding, line):
            grouped_data = re.search(lb_vserver_binding, line).groups()
            data = grouped_data[0]
            return data
```

This returns the result but also results in the extra output.
For example,

**bind lb vserver lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek lb-sg-pr-443-v1-abhishek**

**bind lb vserver lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek-proxy lb-sg-pr-443-v1-abhishek-proxy**

It should have returned only the 1st record till abhishek but it also returns abhishek-proxy

How should I restrict this?

Kindly provide suggestion on the same.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what exactly you're trying to match? Saying that it should have matched the first line and not the second isn't enough.

Comment: So as the lbvs was 'lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek' I wanted it to only match the entries that end with abhishek, like the 1st line returned has 'lb-sg-pr-443-v1-abhishek'. However, it also returns entries that have 'abhishek-proxy', 'abhishek-st', 'abhishek-dc'.

Comment: So the match should start with `bind` and end with `abhishek`?

Comment: I can't tell if you want it to match the entire first line or just `lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek`

Comment: It should be in the 'bind lb vserver' then whatever lbvs comes in with. Like over in this lbvs was 'lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek' so it should have only displayed the record for 'bind lb vserver lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abhishek' and not abhishek-proxy too

Comment: this is still very unclear. `lb-vs-pr-443-v1-abishek-proxy` does match "whatever lbvs comes in with". also, please edit the question directly instead of adding explanation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want matches that end with `'abhishek'`, you can try this:

```
import re
final_list = [line for line in lb_file_memory if re.findall("abhishek$", line)]
```